# Why do I have problems running script/x tasks after installing rails 3 beta?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I installed rails 3 beta in my OSX Leopard. After that, I've created a rails project to test it. From inside its folder, I just can't do script/generate, or even script/server.

It returns '`-bash: script/server: No such file or directory`'. How could I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails 3 has done away with script/*.  Use `rails server`, `rails generate`, etc. while in your app's directory.

Run `rails --help` to get the full list.

Comment: omg! I skipped completely the manuals, I didn't think it would have so many changes :P

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3, instead of using `script/*`, use `rails`. So instead of writing `script/generate` use `rails g` (alias of generate) and instead of `script/server` use `rails s` (alias of server).

The additional usage of port/environment is the same as in Rails 2. So you can add the port 3005 (default is 3000) with production environment as `rails s -p 3005 -e production`. Hope that will solve your problem.